# Почему регулярное выражение не видит в тексте знаки '\' и '+' ?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Код:

```
$ffo = '<h1 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px;">876/8+4';
$rro = '876/8+4'; # получено из $form->param("name1")  при use CGI;
$ffo =~ s/$rro//;
print $ffo;
```

Выводит:

```
<h1 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px;">876/8+4
```

Так же работает если в шаблоне есть '\'. Если плюс убрать или четверку, все отрабатывает.
Посоветуйте красивое решение, плз.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ffo =~ s/\Q$rro\E//;
```

Answer (score 0):

А если:

```
print $ffo if $ffo =~ s/$rro//;
```

или

```
print $ffo if $ffo =~ /$rro$/;
```

Если я не понял чего-то напишите, что именно Вы ожидаете получить? Строку: `padding: 0px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px;`?

Comment: Строку 
<h1 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px;">
Там проблема была в том, что в переменной используемой как шаблон для поиска, есть слеш, плюс, а могут быть любые знаки, переданные в форме.